# Web API Attribute Routing Constraint

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have the following constraint:

```
[Route("api/currencies/{currencyCode:length(3)}", Name="GetCurrencyByCode")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string currencyCode)
```

If I make the following request I get a 405 Method Not Allowed:

```
http://localhost:7475/api/currencies/ZSHK
```

This does make sense however the response message is the standard "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'". I want to be a good REST citizen but this message doesn't give the client any indication about what the actual problem is.

Does anyone have any recommendations for this scenario? Is there a way for me to change the standard message that is returned?

Note - I don't want to create a 'catch all' handler for any 405. I've seen a few of those solutions but I am looking for something more targeted to this specific routing attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Your route is constrained by the length so it will not match and be found, hence the 405 error. You could add an additional route without the constraint that could return a different error or response. Routes with constraints are evaluated before those without so it would match the constrained route if possible before the more generic.